# How can I read large (10MB) byte arrays with Entity Framework and PostgreSQL without using too much memory?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql

When my server application starts it reads about 20 records from my database (using Entity Framework with Npgsl to read from a PostgreSQL database). There are a couple bytea columns, one of them is pretty big. On average it holds about 2.5 MB but some records have upwards of 7MB and ideally it should be able to hold up to 20MB. In total all of the data combined for all the 20 records is 52MB. (but it should be able to handle more in the future)

I read all of these records at once, they are not stored in memory, they are sent to another server and then the DbContext is disposed.

```
    using (var db = new PsqlContext())
    {
        WebApi.Entities.BuilderDungeon[] builderDungeons = db.BuilderDungeons.Where(d => d.UseInGame).Include(d => d.Creator).ToArray();
    }
```

I don't understand why, but after I query this data the server application's memory usage goes from 159MB to 1GB and stays there forever. I'm using Visual Studio's Diagnostic Tools to try and figure out why it's taking up so much memory and it's all coming from the `Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you submit a full, runnable console program that shows this happening?

Comment: The program is quite large and would also require a postgres database to be set up with all the correct data.

Comment: I would not worry too much about that. Applications will request memory and keep it. The fact that the memory is taken from the system does not mean that it is using it. Make it so your program does the exact same operation after a few seconds (i.e. wait for the garbage collector). I bet that you won't see significant memory changes.

Comment: You can use AsNoTracking `db.BuilderDungeons.AsNoTracking().Where()...`

Answer (score 3):

At the lower-level ADO.NET layer, Npgsql buffers entire rows; this allows you to read columns in random-access, but means that memory usage depends on row size, which is bad when columns are huge.

You can efficiently read large (binary) columns by passing [CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.commandbehavior?view=net-7.0#system-data-commandbehavior-sequentialaccess). This means that rows get streamed, memory usage is fixed (and very small), but you have to access columns in the order in which they were requested, and can't read a column more than once. Unfortunately, this mode isn't very compatible with an ORM such as EF Core, so I'd recommend dropping down to ADO.NET for queries loading large rows.

Answer (score 0):

That's how .Net memory allocation works. It allocates memory according to the number of CPU cores you have (a real pain for Kubernetes-based deployments) and also allocates more memory than it needs, roughly doubling it.

One 20 MB array holds, well, 20 MB of memory but to send it to a server you also need to serialize it, probably JSON, which does not have a byte[] type, so it will go in Base64 form which will add another %~25 memory to it, making it 25 MB on top of what you already have, all totaling to 45 MB, excluding all other allocations.

Try using something much more capable like [JetBrains' dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/) to take a snapshot, see what's on the memory, and more importantly where it was allocated.

Comment: There is no base64 or JSON involve in sending anything to PostgreSQL, I'm not sure where that assumption comes from.

Comment: "to a server", I meant the another server OP mentioned in their post. I assume it was not a DB, hence the json format

Answer (score 0):

You should consider storing this binary data for example in Blob Storage, DB entry should only contain information where real data is located in the BlobStorage. This allows future parallelization because for now your solution may have huge bottleneck.

The other thing is that maybe you don't need materialization at this stage so consider removing ToArray() and then process each entry at a time instead of downloading all of them at once.

Regarding the memory size - if you want to see how much memory is taken after your PG context has been disposed use GC.Collect [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=net-6.0)